# Django, error importing view from another app

Tags: python, django, import

I'm trying to import a view from one app to another in my project.
When using this:

```py
from ..from ..KnownLocation.views import KnownLocationView
```

I get the following error:

```
ValueError: attempted relative import beyond top-level package
```

When trying to use:

```py
from triangulationapi.KnownLocation.views import KnownLocationView
```

It's raising the following error.

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'triangulationapi.KnownLocation'
```

my Project tree:

```
├── find_second_gdt
│   ├── admin.py
│   ├── apps.py
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── migrations
│   ├── models.py
│   ├── __pycache__
│   ├── second_GDT_finding
│   ├── serializers.py
│   ├── tests.py
│   ├── urls.py
│   └── views.py
├── __init__.py
├── KnownLocation
│   ├── admin.py
│   ├── apps.py
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── migrations
│   ├── models.py
│   ├── __pycache__
│   ├── serializers.py
│   ├── tests.py
│   ├── urls.py
│   └── views.py
├── manage.py
├── requirements.txt.
└── triangulationapi
    ├── asgi.py
    ├── __init__.py
    ├── __pycache__
    ├── settings.py
    ├── urls.py
    └── wsgi.py
```

And, what's the diffrence between using .. and project.app.view...

I thought it is the same up until now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
from .KnownLocation.views import KnownLocationView
```

Comment: It worked, but pycharm displays it as unresolved reference.